# Combining 2 FFMPEG Commands

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to combine 2 ffmpeg commands, one which creates the video, and another which adds a simple fade to the beginning of the created video. Here's what I have:

```
ffmpeg -y -stream_loop -1 -i "video.mp4" -stream_loop -1 -i "music.mp3" -i "audio.mp3" -filter_complex "[1:a]volume=0.1[a1];[2:a]adelay=5000|5000,apad=pad_dur=10[a2];[a1][a2]amerge=inputs=2,afade=in:st=0:d=5[audio]" -map "0:v" -map "[audio]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 2 -ar 22050 -preset veryfast -shortest "output.mp4"

ffmpeg -y -i "output.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:v]fade=in:0:d=5" -c:a copy -preset veryfast -movflags faststart -fflags genpts "done.mp4"
```

The two commands work perfectly fine, however the second one takes about the same amount of time to process as the first, and I feel it should be relatively easy to do the fade-in during the first encode. For my skillset atleast, I was wrong. Please could someone with more experience lend a helping hand?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a simple filterchain for the video.

`ffmpeg -y -stream_loop -1 -i "video.mp4" -stream_loop -1 -i "music.mp3" -i "audio.mp3" -filter_complex "[1:a]volume=0.1[a1];[2:a]adelay=5000|5000,apad=pad_dur=10[a2];[a1][a2]amerge=inputs=2,afade=in:st=0:d=5[audio]" -vf "fade=in:0:d=5" -map "0:v" -map "[audio]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 2 -ar 22050 -preset veryfast -shortest -movflags faststart "done.mp4"`

Comment: Perfect. Not only does it work as needed, but the combined command is somehow faster than either of the previous ones on their own, so better all-round. Thank you Gyan.